# Benefits of installing compat-wireless?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, adapter

Last week I had problems installing a wireless network adapter in Ubuntu 12.04, and searching at Google many people recommend installing compat-wireless to solve problems of this type. My question is:

What exactly is compat-wireless and what benefits brings?

Are there other options for solving problems with wireless network adapters on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Compat-wireless](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Download/stable/), now just called [compat-drivers](https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Documentation/compat-drivers) is a set of backported kernel drivers. That means, installing the compat drivers gives you drivers that are newer than the ones included in Ubuntu. So if the problem you're having has been addressed in a newer driver version, installing the compat drivers will help you.

You can find compat repositories for Ubuntu [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LinuxWireless#Compat-wireless_from_Ubuntu_repositories).

Answer (score 1):

compat-wireless has been recently renamed to compat-drivers, according to [Linux Wireless](http://linuxwireless.org/)

you can find more info concerning compat-drivers [here](https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Documentation/compat-drivers)